# Excel If Statement if Cell E6 Equal to A then Print Number 25000

Tags: excel

I want create a table in Excel 2013 with two columns. Column one contains five letters From (A to E). Column two is the summation of column one: when cell (E6,E7,E8,E9,E10) contains `A`, then print `25000`; if contains `B`, print `26000`; if contains `C`, print `27000`; if contains `D`, print `28000`; and if contain `E`, print `29000`.

How can I do this in Excel 2013?

Comment: i don't tried anything FOR EXAMPLE when cell E6 contains Letter A print me 25000 in summation cell column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the least complex would probably be (place in F6 and copy down to F10):

```
=25000+(CODE(E6)-65)*1000
```

However, this makes no provision for cells which do not contain anything and relies on the contents actually being the ASCII `A` through `E` characters. For more general formulas, you probably want to account for the cell not containing what you are expecting (e.g. being blank) and usually not rely on the actual `CODE()` of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Please try in F6 and copied down to F10:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E$6:E$10,A1)=5,25000+1000*(ROW()-6),"")
```

This interprets your requirement as (a) a result only where E6:E10 all contain the same one of the five letters and (b) by 'printing' you mean displaying on the screen.